# How can I highlight text in Calibre?

Tags: ebooks, calibre

according to a 4 year-old forum entry at Calibre, they started working on the feature of being able to highlight text, 4 years ago. Does anyone know how if it is implemented yet and how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the [official bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1080721) it would appear that this features hasn't been implemented and there is no timeframe given for when it might get implemented, if ever!

```
Kovid Goyal (kovid) wrote on 2012-11-19: Re: calibre bug 1080721     #1
The calibre viewer currently does not have support for highlighting. It
is on my TODO list, but there is no time frame for when I will be able to
get to it.

 status wontfix

Changed in calibre:
status:  New → Won't Fix
```

This was the [full list of tickets that contained the word "highlight"](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bugs?field.searchtext=highlight&search=Search&field.status%3alist=NEW&field.status%3alist=OPINION&field.status%3alist=INVALID&field.status%3alist=WONTFIX&field.status%3alist=EXPIRED&field.status%3alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.status%3alist=FIXRELEASED&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&assignee_option=any&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.bug_commenter=&field.subscriber=&field.structural_subscriber=&field.tag=&field.tags_combinator=ANY&field.has_cve.used=&field.omit_dupes.used=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.affects_me.used=&field.has_patch.used=&field.has_branches.used=&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches.used=&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints.used=&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints.used=&field.has_no_blueprints=on&orderby=-importance&start=0) in them, nothing there indicated it would be getting implemented anytime soon.

There were other tickets such as this one too: [[Enhancement] PDF to Kindle Highlighting](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1088580).

```
Kovid Goyal (kovid) wrote on 2012-12-11: Re: calibre bug 1088580     #1
This is not worth the effort for me personally. If some one else wants to 
implement it, I will be happy to supply any needed guidance. If so, re-open
the ticket and we can discuss it.

 status wontfix

Changed in calibre:
status:  New → Won't Fix
```

And this one: [Develop a highlighter for calibre ebook viewer on desktop PC](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1093554).

```
Kovid Goyal (kovid) wrote on 2012-12-25: Re: calibre bug 1093554     #1
This is not worth the effort for me personally. If some one else wants to 
implement it, I will be happy to supply any needed guidance. If so, re-open 
the ticket and we can discuss it.

 status wontfix

Changed in calibre:
status:  New → Won't Fix
```

Hopefully you see the pattern here at this point. I would say if it's a feature that you absolutely want you have a couple of options. You could:

1. take up Kovid Goyal's offer and try and code this yourself
2. ask him if he'd be willing to implement it for a fee
3. see if anyone else would be willing to code this up

Comment: @StephanKristyn - you can upvote too 8-)

Comment: About the 2: all users that need that feature could pay a little fees. The users would commit to pay a specific fee of their choice (ex. 5-10€, or anything) that will be paid when the work will be done and approved by one of the main calibre contributor.

Answer (score 0):

Since Calibre 5.0, it is now officially possible to highlight text in ebooks!

https://calibre-ebook.com/new-in/fourteen